# Imports from Jar not resolving

Tags: android, jar, import, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I created a JAR that has two .class files in them. 
I then added the jar to the libs folder and added the dependency into my gradle file by doing this

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

I then run into a strange issue that can be seen in the image below.
[image]

I can reference the class and use its methods, but then I do a clean/build project I get errors because the imports didnt resolve.
I get a `Error:(22, 27) error: package com.android.biomini does not exist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the classes inside the jar should be inside a folder hierarchy similar to the package name. So inside the jar (which is just a zip) you should have *com/android/biomini/BioMiniAndroid.class* ..

One other remark, the 'com.android' package is already used by android so try using something else like *com.yourcompany.biomini*

Comment: spot on. It's been nearly 10 years since I had to create a JAR file :) I'm a little rusty on some of the details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the jar file in libs folder and select 'Add as Library'. It will then get added to build.gradle automatically.